# How to get data from database and display it to another form?

Tags: c#, mysql

Help me on how to get data from database and display to another form?
This photos are the flow of the system.

Flow
1. I will select a row
2. Another Form appears that displays the StartDate and EndDate of the specific row I chose.

These are the remaining errors.

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3lsN.png)
[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vLT.png)

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working. Please post some code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually i'm a newbie in this language. i tried some codes but its not yet complete. And Honestly I didnt know how to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data between forms :

Form1

```
  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nTitle = textBox1.Text;
        string nText = textBox2.Text ;
        Form2 frm = new Form2(nTitle, nText);
        frm.Show();
    }
}
}
```

Form2

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
    }
    public Form2(string title,string txt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = title;
        label1.Text = txt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why the need to pass data from two forms when you can directly call data from database? Unless there are certain necessary conditions when value changes on one of the two forms.

Comment: Because he said : `how to get data from database and display to another form`

Comment: Exactly! Get data from `database` not get data from other form then pass value to this form.

Comment: True. Now to show OP how to pass that value right. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137910/discussion-between-p-pat-and-eak-team).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option of what you can do.

On `Form2`:

Create a `label` or a `textbox` then give it a name like `idtextbox.text`(or whatever you want) or just the `label` to `idlabel` Then set modifier properties  from `private` to `public`.

Then Create a method that loads data from database based from id like this:

```
public void yourMethodName()
    {
        string connection = @"datasource = localhost; database=sub; Uid=root; Password=steph";
        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        string yourQuery = null;

        yourQuery = "SELECT top 1 * from sub.transmittal_transaction WHERE id=@id";
        MySqlCommand executeQuery = new MysqlCommand(yourQuery, connect);
        executeQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        executeQuery.Parameters["@id"].Value = yourtextboxnamehere.Text; // or = your labelname.text
        connect.Open();
        MySqlDataReader datareader = executeQuery.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if (datareader.HasRows)
            {
                datareader.Read();
                yourtextboxnamehere.Text = datareader["id"].ToString();
                startDate.text = datareader["yourStartDateColumnNameHere"].ToString(); // if your using a label it still ends in .text same goes with using textbox to display it on the form.
                endDate.text = datareader["yourEndDateColumnNameHere"].ToString(); // if your using a label it still ends in .text same goes with using textbox to display it on the form.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then on `Form1`

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.yourtextboxnamehere.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

What the code above does is on `Form1` the `cellcontextclick` event would open `Form2` then pass the value of the current rows `id` on datagridview to `Form2` `label` or `textbox` then from there it would read and display `startdate` and `enddate` based on the `id` from the database. But if you want 1 `id` per sheet number as i've noticed on the image then you need just more than this code.

This is also an option:

```
executeQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourtextboxnamehere.Text);
```

instead of:

```
executeQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
executeQuery.Parameters["@id"].Value = yourtextboxnamehere.Text;
```

But this option is considered bad. Read this [Why we need to stop with AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for the reason.

Comment: I tried your code and i think this code is what i need, but then there are some errors can you help me polish these code errors. i will upload screenshots above. thanks

Comment: @Stephii I edited the code also are you sure your using the right connection? There should be no errors if you have MySqlConnection. I forgot to mention that you need to set the textbox>properties>modifiers from `private` to `public`

Comment: Thank you. i already edited the codes. There are 3 remaining errors in form 2.

Comment: I'd be glad to help out. Just show the remaining errors. 
Note*: Also try to understand the code and not just copy paste it.

Comment: I already upload the screenshots above.  Yep I review the codes.

Comment: Edited code and corrected `connect.open;` to `connect.Open();`. My bad. Made this code on notepad++. As for `EndDate1.Text` & `StartDate1.Text` just make sure you created and named `textbox` or `label` that way then the error should disappear.

Comment: Zero Error Yey!. But when i try to run the system there's something wrong in lines. [executeQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);]  and in line [MySqlDataReader datareader = executeQuery.ExecuteReader();]

Comment: Is `id` an `int` or a different type? if its not then just change it to the correct type. in `MySqlDataReader datareader = executeQuery.ExecuteReader();` make sure its not returning 0 or which means there are no rows in your database. I'll edit code and give you an option.

Comment: i change the id type to BigInt. But still has an error.

Comment: Are you sure its `ubs.transmittal_transaction` and not `sub.transmittal_transaction` in your image code at `SELECT` statement?

Comment: i tried some ramdom codes, and i ended up in the above photos.